# Using Runnable Thread to read file and PipeInputStream

Tags: java, lambda, runnable

I am trying to complete an otherwise trivial homework assignment. However, because it is probably so simply - I am not seeing the solution. Here is the code.

```
  final Path sourceFilePath = Paths.get(args[0]);
  final Path sinkFilePath = Paths.get(args[1]);

  final PipedInputStream pipeInput = new PipedInputStream(10000000);
  final PipedOutputStream pipeOut = new PipedOutputStream(pipeInput);
        
  final Runnable fileInTransporter = () -> {
        try {
            //TODO one command that reads from the file, and writes into pipe
            pipeOut.write(0);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //TODO close related pipe
           pipeOut.close();
        }
    };
        
    final Runnable fileOutTransporter = () -> {
        try {
            //TODO one command reads from pipe, and writes into file
            pipeInput.read();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //TODO close related pipe
            pipeInput.close();
        }
        };
        
        new Thread(fileInTransporter, "source-transporter-thread").start();
        new Thread(fileOutTransporter, "sink-transporter-thread").start();
    }
```

I think I am quite confused with the Runnable interface/lamba implementation used. Also, I think the file, sourceFilePath is not read/written into the pipedOutputStream? Somehow I need to read the file into the pipe?

I think the pipe is setup correctly. I just seem to be failing to get the file read into it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PipeInputStream` is a toy. You have no need of it here, or anywhere else. I used it once, in 1998, and quickly removed it. Just read and write in the same thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out.
I used the following code:

```
Files.copy(sourceFilePath, PipeOut);
```

In the first Runnable

Then, in the second Runnable Thread, I used

```
Files.copy(PipeInput, sinkFilePath);
```